# filter array by value based on another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I have an array of cards. And I need to filter it by value word based on another array. only those objects should remain in cards that correspond to the names in the array difficultWords

```
const cards = [ 
  {
      word: 'cry',
    },
    {
      word: 'fishing',
    },
    {
      word: 'fly',
    },
    {
      word: 'hug',
    },
  ],
  [
    {
      word: 'open',
    },
    {
      word: 'play',
    },
    {
      word: 'run',
    },
    {
      word: 'sing',
    },
  ],
.....
let difficultWords = ["cry", "run", "sing"];
```

That's my code: (but id doesn't work)

```
 let wrongCard = cards.forEach(card => {
    card.filter(el => difficultWords.forEach(i => el.word === i));
 }
```

The output should be

```
let wrongCard = [ 
  [
    {
      word: 'cry',
    },
  ],
  [
    {
      word: 'run',
    },
    {
      word: 'sing',
    },
]
```

Comment: How does the expected output relate to the input?

Answer (score 1):

```js
const cards = [
  [
    {
      word: 'cry'
    },
    {
      word: 'fishing'
    },
    {
      word: 'fly'
    },
    {
      word: 'hug'
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      word: 'open'
    },
    {
      word: 'play'
    },
    {
      word: 'run'
    },
    {
      word: 'sing'
    }
  ]
];
let difficultWords = ['cry', 'run', 'sing'];

const wrongCard = cards.map((card) =>
  card.filter((c) => difficultWords.includes(c.word))
);

console.log(wrongCard);
```

Comment: it doesn't work correctly. it returns other objects that are together with the required ones in one array

Comment: @rise can you update your post with exact input and expected value?

Answer (score 0):

you can use `.map` and `.includes` for this.

```
let wrongCard = cards.forEach(card => {
    card.filter(el => difficultWords.forEach(i => el.word === i));
 }
```

because you write `let wrongCard = cards.forEach...`, so I assumed that you wan to assign the result to to `wrongCard`.

to transform an array to another array, `.map` should be used, because `.forEach` will return `undefined`.

next, because `difficultWords` is array of string, and the `word` also is string, to check a value is inside an array, we can use `diffultWords.includes(word)`, this will return `true` is the word is contain in the diffultWords.

```js
const cards = [
  [{ word: "hug" }],
  [{ word: "open" }, { word: "play" }, { word: "hug" }],
  [{ word: "point" }],
];
let difficultWords = ["point", "hug", "frog", "lion"];

const result = cards.map((arr) => {
  return arr.filter((value) => {
    return difficultWords.includes(value.word);
  });
});

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array#map` to create a new array with the filtered values.

```js
const cards = [ 
  [{
      word: 'cry',
    },
    {
      word: 'fishing',
    },
    {
      word: 'fly',
    },
    {
      word: 'hug',
    },
  ],
  [
    {
      word: 'open',
    },
    {
      word: 'play',
    },
    {
      word: 'run',
    },
    {
      word: 'sing',
    },
  ]];
let difficultWords = ["cry", "run", "sing"];
const res = cards.map(x => x.filter(({word}) => difficultWords.includes(word)));
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

> It works, Congrats!!!!

```js
const cards = [
  [{ word: "hug" }],
  [{ word: "open" }, { word: "play" }, { word: "hug" }],
  [{ word: "point" }],
];
let difficultWords = ["point", "hug", "frog", "lion"];

let res = [];
difficultWords.forEach(val => {
  cards.map(item => {
  item.map(e =>{
  if(e.word === val) {
   res.push(e)
  }})
  })
})

console.log(res)
```